# How to output background-image: url this image.jpg

Tags: html, xpath

I want this image how to get this image.jpg as output link. like XPath?

I tried for a few days but no luck is this possible?

```
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://image.jpg&quot;);"></div>
```

Comment: You want to display the image as the background, or you want to display the 'url' as a line of text? You cannot use a remote URL as a background image for a div, but you can use an img tag instead and style it as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the HTML element that you want to extract the background image if (you can do it using document.getElementById or by using jQuery with xpath), then, you need to extract the style related to background image

```
element.style.backgroundImage
```

After that you can manipulate the string however you want, either by splitting by "url" or with regular expression.

Comment: i have something like this //div[@class="vjs-poster"]/*[1]/text()[normalize-space()]'); but its not full i need to add this tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" but dont know how

Comment: //div[@aria-disabled='false' and @class='vjs-poster' and @tabindex='-1']

Comment: this is the full: //div[@class="vjs-poster"]/div[@aria-disabled='false' and @class='vjs-poster' and @tabindex='-1']/*[1]/text()[normalize-space()]');/ ??

Comment: Yes, using this xpath will give you the required element in the question.